# Problems running Golang service using systemd, GORM, MySQL on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, systemd, go-gorm

Apologies if this has already been asked, but my error seems to be from a pretty specific combination of tools and I can't find anything online.

I'm attempting to use systemd on an AWS Ubuntu distro to run a Golang service I created. When I run the service just using `./user-service-linux` or `sudo ./user-service-linux` it works as expected.

To run the service using systemd I've followed a few blog posts online and my file at etc/systemd/system/user.service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=User service
ConditionPathExists=/home/ubuntu/repos/go-api-starter/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
(Changing these to root doesn’t help)
LimitNOFILE=1024

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
startLimitIntervalSec=60

WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/repos/go-api-starter/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/repos/go-api-starter/user-service-linux

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I run the commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable user.service
$ sudo systemctl start user
```

When I run `sudo journalctl -f -u user` to see the result of running the service in the background I see the error:
`panic: Failed to connect to database: %w dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused`
Before this I was getting the error:
`[error] failed to initialize database, got error Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` (not even sure when I fixed this but I spent a lot of time playing around with MySQL authorization policies and passwords)
When I run `systemctl start user` without the `sudo` I get a message about logging into  org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units which isn't something I have the password to for my ubuntu user.

If I run `mysql -u root -p` I can connect fine using the same credentials as the config file that GORM is using in the Go project, but if I just run `mysql -p` I get the error:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`
(Not sure what this password should be but I try the only password I’ve ever set for MySQL)

To update the MySQL password for 'ubuntu'@'localhost' I tried
`ALTER USER ‘ubuntu’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY 'newPass';`
And got the error
`ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'ubuntu'@'localhost'`

I realize this is a lot of commands and error messages, but I'm hoping someone has experienced some of this before and can point me in the right direction. It seems like the crux of the issue is getting Go/GORM or users ubuntu/root to be able to access MySQL, but I can't find much information on how to configure that and when I try to set passwords in MySQL I get an error message. I'd love to understand what's going on here and how to configure this correctly if anyone has experience with this.

I tried using linux systemd to run a Golang service and was expecting is to run successfully in the background, but it fails and I get various error messages about not being able to connect to the database (MySQL).

Comment: In your systemd service file, `User=ubuntu` and `Group=ubuntu` do not refer to the MySQL user. These are the users and groups under which the Golang service will run. Please double check the username and password of mysql, check the mysql is running, check the Golang service is using the correct credentials.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC I've tried changing the mysql user in the config file of my Go program as well (I've set it to ubuntu as well as another custom user I made) but the error message Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' persists. Any ideas where this could be coming from?